# How to change the default width of container in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: css, gridview, materialize

The default width of `container` is [set to 70%](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) in `MaterializeCSS`:

> The container class is not strictly part of the grid but is important
>   in laying out content. It allows you to center your page content. The
>   container class is set to ~70% of the window width. It helps you
>   center and contain your page content. We use the container to contain
>   our body content.

How could this be changed?

Comment: If you set width:100%; it wont work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just override the property by making sure that your style is read by the browser after linking to, or importing materialize.css

You would need to copy and change these values:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 90%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative easy way would be to not use materialize's *.container* class but create your own class and wrap it into your code. In the CSS style of your custom class, add

```css
.myContainer{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its a single container easily :

```
<div class="container" style="width:85%">
```

if it is more than one container then derive a class:

```
.wide-container 
{
   .container;
   width: 85%;
}
```

then use it like :

```
<div class="wide-container">
```